# JQuery Mobile Demo code doesn't match my output

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to copy the demo code for [Flip Switch on jQuery Mobile](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/docs/widgets/sliders/switch.php)

```
<form>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="flip-7">Flip toggle switch:</label>
        <select name="flip-7" id="flip-7" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
            <option value="off">Off</option>
            <option value="on">On</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Aiming for something like this:
[image: Screen Capture]

But I end up with something like this:
[image]

It is driving me crazy, cause I know my JQuery Mobile script is loading, but I don't seem to get the same result as they argue it should. This happens basically for most of the items, specially handling Forms and Popups. I try classes and so on, with no avail.

You guys have any reference tips for this?

Comment: Maybe you have missed including the CSS file

Comment: Either you are missing css file or you are missing jquery.mobile file.

Comment: Which are the css files you are including in here??

Comment: and more importantly include the link of your program or jsfiddle.

Comment: its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/Q7g3F/1/ you are either missing css file or jQuery Mobile's framework. care to show the complete code of your page?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

Comment: The code to build it is as follows:

Comment: var content = '<form id="'+table+'">';
    for (var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++) {
    content += '<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-mini="true">'+
    '<label for="'+results.rows.item(i).id+'">'+results.rows.item(i).data+'</label>'+
        '<select name="'+results.rows.item(i).id+'" id="'+results.rows.item(i).id+'" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">'+
        '<option value="off">No</option>'+
        '<option value="on">Yes</option>'+
        '</select>'+
        '</div>';
    }
    content += '</form>';
 $(".settings-content").empty();
    $(".settings-content").append(content);

Comment: @X-Factor It runs "well" here: [link] http://jsfiddle.net/Q7g3F/1/ but it just doesn't at mine

Comment: @X-Factor Sorry wrong link before! [link] http://jsfiddle.net/wigiri/PkKLd/

Comment: @Wigiri, its the issue of your dynamic content, not the jquery mobile or css issue, it also happened with me once, try creating static elements. I dont think static elements won't get the style (they will be styled as they should be with jquery.mobile). Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i got your problem, its not your issue its the basic issue, the jquery is only applied to the elements which are in dom not on runtime this issue also happend with me. there could be two solutions

Try calling `.trigger("create")` on the element with the new content.

According to the jQuery Mobile docs, "The create event is suited for enhancing raw markup that contains one or more widgets."

or load the jquery.mobile again.

Comment: based on my JSFiddle, where should I call the .trigger("create")?? I tried $(".settings-content").trigger("create"); right before the $(".settings-content").append(content); with no success

Comment: you have to create your content $(content).trigger("create");

Comment: after appending the content, use $(content).trigger("create"); This will do the trick. As if this is the issue of dynamic data binding;

Comment: just now my header bar is no longer fixed...do you have an idea what could be causing it?

Comment: i dont think, it should be something else ?? check your code, because .trigger("create") doesnot cause error.

Comment: Check the JSFiddle ([link] http://jsfiddle.net/wigiri/PkKLd/) and resize the viewer of the running site (bottom right frame) so you need to scroll down all the "items", then click on the label, and the headbar disappears, then click again and it comes back, is it normal behaviour??

Comment: Use this if you dont want your header bar hides:

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">

Comment: Worked indeed! kudos to you!

Comment: Do +1 to my reputation @Wigiri ;) and in comment to, just upvote my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the entire code(tested in google chrome):
Make sure you have kept javascript enabled on your browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css">
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="flip-7">Flip toggle switch:</label>
    <select name="flip-7" id="flip-7" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
        <option value="off">Off</option>
        <option value="on">On</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Also, check your javascript console for errors. This will prove helpful if the issue still remains unresolved.

Comment: I used         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css">
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script> and with no avail

Comment: Be adviced I'm using Cordova 2.4

Comment: This example does give me the desired output:         <!-- Main page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="main">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#settings" onclick="db.transaction(queryFoodDBAll);">Settings</a>
            <h1 class="content-header">Deeside</h1>
        </div>

            <div class="home">
            </div>
        </div>